# Python, How to replace a complete line which contents a string text?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a text file which contents the credentials to access a my app, example off my text file

```
#cat /etc/app/paswords
petter@domain.com    $8324dhedberhnnhdbcdhgvged
userhappy@domain.com    $2349cmjedcnecbcdfrfrrf8839
```

the spaces are tab's 
I want to change the password hash or the complete line whith a new password

I have the following code:

```
#cat passreplace.py
domain = "midomain.com"
user = "userhappy"
email = user + "@" + domain
print email
if email in open('/etc/app/passwords').read():
        print "User already exist!! one moment change your password"
        #code to remplace password
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

`fileinput` is a good choice for this one.

```
import fileinput

email = username + password

for line in fileinput.input('/etc/app/passwords', inplace=True):
    if email in line:
        print("User already exists! Change password now!")
        username,password = line.split('\t')
        old_pass = input("Enter old password: ")
        if old_pass != password:
            # do something
        new_pass = input("Enter new password: ")
        confirm = input("Confirm new password: ")
        if new_pass != confirm:
            # do something
        print("\t".join([email, new_pass]), end="")
    else:
        print(line, end="")
```